# Typescript - convert type of mongoose ObjectId to string when sharing between backend and frontend

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I am trying to create few types based on mongo schema models and sharing the same with front end in mono repo.

Example type:

```
import { Types } from "mongoose";

export interface Profile {
  userId: Types.ObjectId;
  education: {
    university: Types.ObjectId;
  };
}
```

My Profile Schema use this Profile interface to define types and the same interface is used in front end. Since front end does not (need to) know about mongoose types, I would like to have the `userId` and `education.university` as string. Btw when I get api response from server in front end I get these values as string only.

I have tried a TS mapper as beautifully defined [here](https://kamranicus.com/typescript-overriding-specific-property-types-mapped-conditional/). This solved my problem partially - I can see `userId` being converted to string in front end. But this does not solve the nested object `education`. I can define `education` as separate type and use the mapper, but I think this is not a scalable way. I would like to have the mapper to handle the type conversion of the nested types as well.

`typeMapper.ts`

```
import { Types } from "mongoose";

type MapObjectIdToString<PropType> = PropType extends Types.ObjectId
  ? string
  : PropType;

  export type MapDbObject<T> = {
    [PropertyKey in keyof T]: MapObjectIdToString<T[PropertyKey]>;
  };
```

I am converting `Profile` type like this

```
export type UiProfile = MapDbObject<Profile>; // here `userId` is string, but `university` is still Types.ObjectId
```

Is there a way to update my TS Mapper to convert all fields including fields inside nested object from `Types.ObjectId` to `string`? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recursive type will do it:

```
type StringIds<T> = T extends Types.ObjectId ? string : T extends Record<any, any> ? {
    [K in keyof T]: StringIds<T[K]>;
} : T;
```

Also works with arrays. Try it yourself below:

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wRlZLm)